# Make PNG Logo bigger Size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, less

has anyone an Idea, how I can resize our Logo?
It has a height of 52px but it only shows a height of 39px when I inspect it.

```
http://www.loccoz.com/
```

Comment: One of your media queries is capping the max height of the logo. `@media (min-width: 992px)
.navbar-brand-image > img {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    max-height: 65%;
    width: auto;
}`

Comment: @Granny Have you an idea where it could be in Less? Because when i add the code at the End of the less files it's broke the side.

Comment: I dont know what your less looks like. So unless you make a working snippet i cannot help you with that.

Comment: Understandable. The Problem is it's not only one less file it 30. So i's look like i must add it on the variable.less file

Comment: If you inspect the image, you will see the file where the media querie hides in.

Comment: Found it was in an less named navbar.less xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I inspected img tag of yours, there is a setting of **max-height:65%** for **.navbar-brand-image > img**. Increase the percentage to **max-height:100%** property. it will work.

Comment: Thanks you, you helped me a lot.